# Where to get the keys to Eclipse in Silent Hill?

Tags: silent-hill-series

As written on the map that's inside the house by the doghouse.
Don't answer with a guide, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markers on the map indicate where you should be looking.

One is at the east end of Finney St:

> in the trunk of the police car (the arrow on the map).

One is at the end of Ellroy St:

> in a mailbox (the circle on the map).

One is between Finney and Matheson:

> on the basketball court down the alley (this alleyway is the long line on the map).

Comment: I thought I should be looking in the area that's written "Keys of Eclipse", now I realize I should look at the other markings. Thanks.